# Can I upload a VM with Windows Server 2012 Trial Version to Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012, azure-virtual-machine

I would like to prepare a virtual machine in my host before upload it to Windows Azure. What if I use a Windows Server 2012 trial version? When uploaded it, the trial version licence will be replaced by windows azure licence or my VM will be available just for 90 days?

Answer (score 0):

If you prepare your VM image with the trial license and upload it, it will continue just be the trial license.  They do not change anything on your VM when you push it up.  It will stop when your 90 days are up just as if it were still on your local host machine.

I'm not sure why you would want to do this.  If you are just wanting to set something up locally with all the software you need installed, etc. it may just be better to create a Windows Server instance from the online gallery and do the installations in the cloud.  Unless you have a really good connection (meaning fast) you're likely to spend a great deal of time pushing the final VHD up to Azure anyway.  If you start with a VHD from the gallery it will have the OS installed and you can then just get the software you need to install up there.  I've seen people do that by pushing up the software into BLOB storage and then getting it back down on the server in the cloud, or I've also seen people create a small VHD data disk locally that is just large enough to fit their software installs, load that up into their account and attach it to the server they want to install stuff to.  Then detach it when they are done with the installs.